# List rendering for javascript web components (custom elements)

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, w3c, custom-element

Imagine I have two custom elements like that:

```
    <accordeon>
       <collapse>
          <div slot="header">...</div>
          <div slot="body">...</div>
       </collapse>
    </accordeon>
```

I will have multiple `collpases` inside `accordeon`. (`collapse` hide/show body when clicked). In html I can choose and style the content of both `collapse` slots.

Now I have a problem, I receive large JSON array to be shown as `accordeon`. If I pass that array to `<accordeon>`, then I think I should render `<collapse>` elements inside accordion inside for loop. But then I can't use `collapse` as a custom element, I mean I wouldn't be able to style and manage the content of slots of `collapse`, so it won't be flexible to use as components (because I believe custom element shouldn't be modified from inside that element).

So I think I need something like v-for in Vue and ngFor in angular, But I don't think this will be trivial. so what should I do in this case for rendering list?

P.S: take into account that after that I will need infinity scroll.

Comment: you've answered your own question 'ngFor in React...', ngFor is for angular ;)

Comment: I just misspeled it and edited before your comment

Comment: So I should use this type of loop rendering? Is there any documentation or example how can I do that?

Comment: "I mean I wouldn't be able to style and manage the content of slots of collapse, so it won't be flexible to use as components (because I believe custom element shouldn't be modified from inside that element)." Can you explain this bit ?

Comment: I mean if I only write <accordion></accordion>, and do all the stuff (like constructing collapses according to json array) inside that element in the background, then this component won't be reusable at all.